# How do you add a unique primary key field automatically in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database

I am using SQL Server 2012 and need to add a column with a unique primary key. I am about to load several hundred thousand records BULK and just discovered repetition in the field I was going to use. Have seen `SEQUENCE` and `GUID`. Need some guidance on the best choice and how to go about setting this up so that the key field is populated during the bulk load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a slight update on what’s already posted that includes details for adding primary key constraint

```
alter table database.schema.table_t
    add ID_column int identity(1,1)
    primary key (ID_column)
```

If you already set the primary key on this table just go and remove it before you execute this statement.

Comment: Thanks you guys have been very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

When you create your table in which you want to insert information create an `IDENTITY` column. That will serve as an auto-populating column with a unique number for each record.

Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) that might help you.

If you have already created your table just change this query to what suits to your table name and run it in order to add the new column you requested.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
ADD COLUMN unique_id IDENTITY (1,1)
```

Comment: If this has worked for you, please do not forget to mark the answer as the correct answer.